# Default VS2010 IList type in Intellisense/ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

Let's say I have the following function:

```
public IList<string> Foo()
{
  // code goes here
}
```

I'm used to being able to type in `return new` and as soon as I hit [SPACE], Intellisense pops up and suggests `List<string>` but right now it defaults to `ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<string>` and the only other option in there is `TrackableCollection<string>`. I recently rebuilt my dev environment and I no longer get this functionality. I THOUGHT that this was the default. I've never had this problem before (and have built more than half a dozen development environments with VS2010).

**What setting(s) do I change to get this back?**

Comment: Not sure. Works fine for me with VS2010 + ReSharper 6. If you look in ReSharper > Options > IntelliSense > General, is the "ReSharper" radio button selected?

Comment: @Joe White: Yup, that's set to `ReSharper`

Comment: It works in my ReSharper 5.1, VS2010.

Comment: It works fine in some of my VS2010s as well. Just not one of them, which was a clean install. Made no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured the answer out to this. Specific versions (but not all) of Telerik's JustCode was causing this. Upgrading, disabling, or uninstalling JustCode finally made this problem go away.